# Make object not receive cast shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I know you can make an object not cast shadows on others by disabling Shadow in Ray Visibility. But how can you make an object not receive shadows cast by other objects?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it in CYCLES yet. I tried to achieve it and even googled for this problem with no results. In BLENDER INTERNAL you just uncheck the Receive box in Shadow panel, but CYCLES is a different story.

Comment: have the object inquestion be in a different layer than the other shadow-casting-objects

Comment: That would achieve this, but causes lots of other hassle.

Answer (score 1):

This should now be easily possible with the light linking feature in Blender 4.0

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.